# What does registering a DLL do?

Tags: windows, com, dll

I know how to register dlls but I've never really been sure why I'm doing it or under what conditions a dll must be registered.  Could somebody explain or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When a DLL is registered, the `DllRegisterServer` method entry point in your DLL is invoked.  Similarly, `DllUnregisterServer` is invoked when a DLL is unregistered.

As described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682162(VS.85).aspx):

> Instructs an in-process server to
>   create its registry entries for all
>   classes supported in this server
>   module. If this function fails, the
>   state of the registry for all its
>   classes is indeterminate.

For COM DLLs, you will need to implement your own `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer` entry point methods which do the registering/unregistering as appropriate.  Example code for `DllRegisterServer` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376682(VS.85).aspx).

The end result of registering a DLL is that all of the CLSIDs for the components in the DLL are registered under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`.  This allows `CoCreateInstance` to find the correct server when instantiating COM objects from another DLL or application.

`DllUnregisterServer` will do the reverse, and remove all of the CLSIDs from the registry that were put in there by `DllRegisterServer`.

More general information about `DllRegisterServer` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369359.aspx).

Comment: When I create an ActiveX DLL in VB6 I don't have to implement DllRegisterServer.

Answer (score 9):

What is most commonly referred to as DLL registering is when it implements a COM object. regsvr32 ensures that an instance of the object can be created. When e.g. VBScript uses New or CreateObject(), the registration ensures that COM knows what DLL to load in order to make a new instance, whether by name or CLSID.

See ["the layman's explanation"](https://chewychong.wordpress.com/2004/08/23/layman-s-explanation-of-regscvs-regasm-regsvr32/) for a (very) brief summary.

Comment: Link is broken. Please provide an alternate.

Comment: Done. Also archived as https://web.archive.org/web/20170222094351/https://chewychong.wordpress.com/2004/08/23/layman-s-explanation-of-regscvs-regasm-regsvr32/

Answer (score -2):

Simply see the source code of regsvr32.exe

Comment: I was surprised to find out that this source code is actually available with Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177531.aspx

Comment: _"Simply"_ ... (at least is subjective, if not a bit loaded)