# Registering the WIN32 Dll

Tags: c++

I want to register my Win32Dll to specific path in registry using Regsvr32. I will create subkey under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (eg:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ALGORITHM) and under this hierarchy i want to register my Win32 Dll..How can i achieve to this?

Comment: Win32 dll doesn't get resigtered using Regsvr32 until they have DllRegisterServer and DllUnRegisterServer methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register a Dll in LOCAL_MACHINE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420949/register-a-dll-in-local-machine)

Comment: @MarsRover: That's just a convention. Convenient and widespread, but still not magic.

Comment: @MSalters: IMO COM Dlls get registered into Registery not plain Win32 Dll. I mean what does one mean by registered? You can create registery entries for you dlls component, but that doesn't mean registered.

Comment: @MarsRover: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620858/what-does-registering-a-dll-do . Registering a DLL is just a matter of creating the right entries.